# Permanently change caption of label in one userform from another userform VBA

Tags: vba, userform, designer

So I am attempting to use the following function to change the caption of a label on an active userform form another overlaid userform:

```
Function changeMsgFunc(ByVal targetUF As Object, targetCtrl As Control, targetStr As String)

Dim i As Long, targetUFStr As String, targetCtrlStr As String
targetUFStr = targetUF.Name
targetCtrlStr = targetCtrl.Name

With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(targetUFStr).Designer
    For i = 0 To .Controls.Count
        If TypeName(.Controls(i)) = "Label" And .Controls(i).Name = targetCtrlStr Then
            .Controls(i).Caption = targetStr
            Exit For
        Else
            ' DO NOTHING
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Function
```

where `targetUF`, `targetCtrl` and `targetStr` are all set in another `Sub` ( the one that call the function. For some reason, this line:

```
For i = 0 To .Controls.Count
```

gives `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.`

I've scoured the internet to see if anyone else has had the issue I am having, but no luck (for everyone else, a code similar to this worked - I've essentially changed how the various strings are passed to the `With` block and `For` loop.)

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is the 'Trust access to VBA Project object model' ticked, in the **Developer Macro Settings** section, in the Macro Settings, in the **Trust Center**?

Comment: Yes. I’ve used similar codes to permanently alter other userforms. Could it be because the userform I’m trying to change is active?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.